# BehaviorSubject is not emitting value in angular

Tags: angular

In UserService class i have created BehaviorSubject of User.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from '../domain/user';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private baseUrl: String = "http://localhost:8080/tasty/user";

  public data: User = null;
  private loggedInUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>( this.data );


  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
  }

  setLoggedInUser( user: User ): void {
    this.data = user;
    this.loggedInUser.next( this.data );
  }

  getLoggedInUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.loggedInUser.asObservable();
  }

  getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.http.get( this.baseUrl + "/getUsers" )
      .toPromise()
      .catch( e => e );
  }

  getUserByEmail( email: String ): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.post( this.baseUrl + "/findByEmail", email )
      .toPromise()
      .catch( e => e );
  }

  addUser( user: User ): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.post( this.baseUrl + "/addUser", user )
      .toPromise()
      .catch( this.handleError );
  }


  updateUser( user: User ): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.post( this.baseUrl + "/updateUser", user )
      .toPromise()
      .catch( this.handleError );
  }

  private handleError( error: any ): Promise<any> {
    console.error( 'Some error occured', error );
    return Promise.reject( error.message || error );
  }


}
```

then once i have usercomponent which update user from onSubmit method which basically call method of userservice's updateUser() and then after i call setLoggedInUser() but in usercomponent i do not get updated user from subscribe().

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { User } from '../../domain/user'
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './user.component.css' ]
} )
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  loggeInUser: User;
  userForm;
  isUpdated: boolean;
  constructor( private userService: UserService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {

    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
      id: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.id ),
      email: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.email, [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength( 8 ) ] ),
      firstName: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.firstName, [ Validators.required ] ),
      lastName: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.lastName, [ Validators.required ] ),
      mobile: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.mobile ),
      authToken: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.authToken ),
      provider: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.provider ),
      address: this.formBuilder.group( {
        id: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.id ),
        appartmentNo: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.appartmentNo ),
        streetNo: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.streetNo ),
        street: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.street ),
        city: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.city ),
        province: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.province ),
        postalCode: new FormControl( this.loggeInUser?.address?.postalCode )
      } )
    } )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getLoggedInUser().subscribe( user => {
      this.loggeInUser = user;
      console.log( this.loggeInUser, 'this.loggeInUser' );
      this.userForm.patchValue( this.loggeInUser )
    }

    );
  }

  onSubmit( values ) {

    this.userService.updateUser( values )
      .then( e => {
        console.log( e, 'e from update user' );
        this.userService.setLoggedInUser( e );

      } )
      .catch( e => console.log( e, 'e' ) );
  }


}
```

And my user class is

```
import { Address } from "./address";
export class User {
    id?: string;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    authToken: string;
    provider: string;
    mobile?: number;
    address?: Address;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am fairly new in angular.

Comment: are you sure the `setLoggedInUser` is called?

Comment: Yes it is being called

Comment: is there any specific errors happening? and if the `setLoggedInUser ` is being called then  can you check the parameter being passed to it if it is of type `User` (console in the service)

Comment: Yes actually in patchvalue method of form i was getting error as address formcontrol was null which stops subscribe of user to emit further. By the way thanks for your help @Kardon63